# Python - Get the top 5 items from dictionary type column pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I've a dataframe which one of the columns are a dictionary, I'm getting a huge number of items inside that dictionary which is causing me memory problems. The solution was get only the first 10 items from that dictionary. I already have the code but it gives a error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'
```

I made a sample code just to show you my problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

res = pd.DataFrame([])
res_tmp = pd.DataFrame([])
d = {'club': ['A1', 'B1'], 'score': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    total = int(row['score']) * -1
    res_tmp = res_tmp.append({'today': str(datetime.datetime.now()), 'total': total}, ignore_index=True)
    res = res.append({'club': row['club'], 'details': res_tmp.to_dict('dict')},ignore_index=True)

res['details'] = res['details'].apply(lambda y: (sorted(y.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))[:1])
```

What I am doing wrong? Note: In example I just have two rows that's why I put the top 1 instead of top 10

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message tells you, there is no defined value ordering for dicts.  If you want to sort the dicts, you must provide the function you write to define the sort order.  You extracted the value, but you also have to convert the dict to some type that *does* have `<` defined.  For instance:

```
key = lambda x: list(x[1].values())
```

Comment: Like this "res['details'] = res['details'].apply(lambda y: list(y[1].values()))" ?

Comment: Not quite: you omitted the `sorted` call.  If you run your suggested version, the result will not be useful.  :-)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand how to solve the problem :)

Comment: In your original code, replace your `key` argument with the one I supplied.

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting this: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

Comment: Okay; if you have both floats and strings in your dict, then you need to resolve how you want them sorted.  That's the gist of my answer.  You command Python to sort you dicts, but there is no built-in order.  You have to define that, depending on what *you* see as the "first 10 items".  Your description and your example don't match, and the example doesn't illustrate what you expect for output, so all I can do is suggest a workaround for the general problem you describe.